# Do i need to have a domain name for firebase deeplinks to redirect users to my flutter app on playstore?

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

So I integrated firebase dynamic links into my app using the docs alongside some youtube videos, and although the link doesn't open up in any browser, it shows "site can't be reached error" it opens up if i have the app installed. However if the app isn't installed, i want it to take the user to my app on playstore, but it doesn't seem to be doing that. I wanted to know if i needed to buy a domain to fix this issue or am i missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to purchase a domain to get up and running with Firebase deep links. Google will provide you with a project related .web.app (For example: my_example_project_name.web.app) domain to use.

If you go through the dynamic link builder within the Firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/) you will be given options to select what happens when the link is clicked. If package names are correct and it is clicked you can ensure your app then opens, this can be dealt with in-app. You can also tick a box to say take me to the app store if the app is not downloaded.

Comment: it turned out that the reason it wasnt working was because the package name i was using was wrong. As soon as i fixed that, it started working